# How do I make DD-WRT re-use static leases for wifi clients?

Tags: networking, dhcp, dd-wrt

I am trying to configure static leases for DD-WRT, so that my phone gets the same IP address every time it connects via wifi. I have set up a static lease under Services/Services/Static Leases. This works the first time, but the second time that the phone connects (e.g. disable wifi and re-enable, or go out and come back home) the original lease is still active and the phone gets assigned a new, different IP address.

Is there some way to make DD-WRT re-issue the static lease? It's the same device, same MAC address etc. I just end up with two entries on the Status/LAN/DHCP Clients page for it.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any DHCP debug logs or packet captures to share?

Comment: There is a possibility that this is a bug in the DD-WRT software: static leases should be re-issued to the proper MAC address, irrespective of the lease time.

Comment: Where can I get logs from? Yes, I'm thinking it could be a bug. I'm using the latest stable release for my router (Buffalo WZR-D1800H, v24-SP2). Should I upgrade? It's a couple of years old now.

Comment: You should definitely upgrade. The router database at dd-wrt.com is borked. Look at the forums and grab a newer/latest release.

Comment: I'm just a little nervous about using beta firmware. Is there a way to find a recent stable release? The FTP site doesn't seem to give any hints. I require stability.

Comment: I did the update, it still doesn't work.

Comment: It might be possible that another device takes that IP address so it cannot be reallocated again. Try to give the phone a static IP address that is outside of the range allocated by DD-WRT. For example, if allocations go from 1 to 150, give the phone the static address of 151.

Comment: Thanks harrymc, I did try that. My DHCP range is 100-150, and I allocated 99 to the phone.

Comment: Is this happening only with this phone? Try setting up a few static dhcps for few other macs/ devices, restart and see if the behavior changes

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is an infinite lease time.
For that you have to leave the lease time box empty during the creation of the static lease.

Comment: I'll try it and report back.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.